# bash loop over files mysterious bug

Tags: bash, while-loop, stdin, mplayer

Can anyone tell me what's going on here:

This:

```
find . -name "*.mp3" | while read fname ; do 
    echo "$fname"; 
    ls -l "$fname"; 
    echo mplayer "$fname" ; 
    echo "$fname" ;
done
```

works absolutely fine as far as I can see, but if I actually try to run mplayer instead of echoing the command:

```
find . -name "*.mp3" | while read fname ; do 
     echo "$fname"; 
     ls "$fname"; 
     mplayer "$fname" ; 
     echo "$fname" ; 
done
```

Then it plays one file and then goes haywire.

I'm thinking that mplayer must be interacting with read somehow, but I am not wise in the ways of bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is correct. `find` outputs its list of files to `stdout`. You pipe that in to a second process: your `while` loop. In this loop, both `read` and `mplayer` read from `stdin`. `read` will read the first filename, and `mplayer` will read all the rest of the input as if you were controlling it via the keyboard while running.

The easiest solution is to add `</dev/null` after mplayer, but it may not be happy if it can't read from `stdin`. Other solutions are to use a separate file descriptor for your `find | read` part, or use a `for`-loop instead.

Comment: thank you, you are some sort of amazing bash genius and I will accept your answer as soon as I am allowed to!

Comment: Do not use a `for` loop and YMMV with `find | read`, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-noconsolecontrols` option of `mplayer`. It makes it ignore the standard input, so it doesn't steal characters from it and `read` can process them, and `mplayer` doesn't behave strangely, interpreting file names as commands coming from the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead:

```
#!/bin/env bash
while IFS= read -r -d '' fname <&9; do 
     printf '%s\n' "$fname"
     ls "$fname"
     mplayer "$fname"
     printf '%s\n' "$fname"
done 9< <(find . -name '*.mp3' -print0)
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: The `9` is an arbitrarily chosen number of a file descriptor that is not (yet) in use somewhere else. You can choose whatever number you like, as long as it's free, which mostly means >2.

Comment: Right, I used 9 because the FAQ uses 9 and I wanted the OP to be able to see clearly/easily how the FAQ solution is applied to his problem.